# amazon EC2 - How to make wp-config.php to writable?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions

I'm using Amazon EC2 with Bitnami wordpress.

I recently tried to use plugins, they install and activate well, but there are still errors. Those errors look like permission errors.

Also, perhaps, how to make the whole wordpress directory writable?
I'm only accessing through SSH.

Some of the errors:

"A definition of a siteurl or homeurl was detected in your wp-config.php, but the file is not writable.

Set your wp-config.php to writable and reload this page."

From W3 total Cache:

[image: W3 total cache error]

Comment: Please add the error messages you get back.

Comment: one is: " A definition of a siteurl or homeurl was detected in your wp-config.php, but the file is not writable.

Set your wp-config.php to writable and reload this page."

Comment: I would recommend updating your question with all the errors.

Answer (score 22):

To enable it, please enter the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 664 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is awesome solution.

Comment: in lightsail, my wp-config.php file was in the folder stack/wordpress.  Then I rebooted the server via the lightsail admin screen.  the 'sudo chmod' command worked correctly with the proper folder name

Answer (score -2):

Your FTP user doesn't have write permission to the folder.

you can add this line to your wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

assign wordpress folder bitnami:daemon  and assign 775 permission

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon wordpressfolder
sudo chmod -R 775 wordpressfolder
```